# Returning ifstream by value compiles

Tags: c++

I noticed that I am able to return a `std::ifstream` from a function by value without the compiler giving me any errors related to a deleted copy constructor. This shouldn't work because ifstreams shouldn't be copyable so I imagine it is inlining the function in some way? Does anyone have an explanation for this?

I am running Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.6 with Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31) g++

```
ifstream enterFile(){
    ifstream input("hello.txt");
    return input;
}


int main() {
    ifstream f = enterFile();
    string line;
    while(getline(f, line)) {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    cout << "===== Done" << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `ifstream` cannot be copied but can be moved, `input`  was returned by move constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The copy constructor may be deleted, but the move constructor is declared and accessible. When you return a local variable from a function, overload resolution is first performed as though it was an rvalue. That chooses which c'tor to call. If the object is move constructible (has a c'tor that can bind to an rvalue reference), the code will be well formed.

Even after all that is done, the RVO is probably applied and the object isn't moved at all. So `f` and `input`, though in different scopes, will refer to the same object.

That's the gist of it up to C++14. From C++17 onward even the move c'tor need not always be available, thanks to guaranteed copy elision. You'd notice this difference if you try to return a pure rvalue instead if a named local.

Comment: I guessed something along these lines but I'm trying to make the fact explicit. For example, it doesn't look like it's calling the move constructor because I have some print statements there that aren't showing. My last guess was RVO but I tried disabling that with a `-fno-elide-constructors` to no avail. Is there any way I can pinpoint what specific feature is causing this?

Comment: @gowrath - Print statements where? Your own code moves an `ifstream`.

Comment: I forked my own class ifstreamv from std::ifstream so I could put print which type of constructors were being called.

Comment: Actually, some further investigation shows it is RVO and if not that, the move constructor is called. I disabled RVO by having a runtime condition on the return from the enterFile() method and it printed my print statement in the move constructor :)